# Local Function Call on itself

Tags: python, variables, recursion, global, local

Learning python, searched for this problem, and having a hard time figuring out why I'm getting the behavior that I am. I'm getting the correct output, but I'm not sure why, I'd just like to know going forward just to better understand this concept. Let me explain:

if create a function such as

```
def function(list):
```

and I then call this function on a list x

```
print function(x)
```

if I were then to recall this function with the function itself like so:

```
def function(list):
     function(list)
```

why does that recursive call still hold the values for x which was called globablly?

Comment: because you are passing `x` as the parameter `list`, ie `list` references the same object as `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "list" in the parameter list is then passed to the next call.  Each one is a direct copy of x.  It's not the global x; it's the local copy in the variable list that gets passed down.

Note that this is a direct example of infinite recursion: there's no way to stop the chain of the function calling itself.  Instead, you might want something like

```
def function(list):
    if len(list) == 0:
        return "end"
    else
        return function(list[1:]) + list[0]
```

A recursive function needs a terminating condition and something to return.